# not find the appropriate bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibitem

**Which bibliography style in the following picture?**

I tried to all 100+ bibliography styles in [the link](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/632.htm%7EmainFrame), but some of them look like, but none are exactly the same. (ACM style looks a bit like) On the other hand, if we are not professional, anyone doesn' t suggest creating/editing a bibliography style. (I am not professional)

I have a lot of references. So, it is very difficult to add manually Bibitem.

Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: The easiest would probably be to use `biblatex`,  with one of its styles closest to  what you want, and patch it to get exactly what you want. It uses a latex syntax, and further, there's  the `xpatch` package which can help do it.

Comment: Thanks for your interest dear @bernard. But I am not good, could you explain more or give me some examples

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the examples directory in the documentation, which contains examples of various styles, with the codes and their results . If you don't have it installed, you can see it   [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc). Then, I suppose you'll ba able to build a small code, and explain what should possibly be modified, either cchoosing different options or patching the code of some biblatex macros.

Comment: If this is for a journal of publisher submission `biblatex` may be out of the question (`biblatex` requires a very different workflow than classical BibTeX, not all publishers like that). So before you start with `biblatex` double check with your editor.

Comment: This is a reference format of a journal to submit a paper dear @moewe